Initialise version control of GitHub repository using git
how do I initialise version control of a repository on GitHub using git? I am new to GitHub and git. have been searching for tutorial online but I don't really find one that could help.
I have installed git on my terminal and tried running some git commands on terminal but I don't really get what it actually do to the GitHub repository. can you initialise version control of a GitHub repository using git? if yes, how to do so?

Does this answer your question? Create a GitHub repository from command line

Yes but I still can't connect my GitHub with the local repository. I tried the push origin command. but unfortunately I can't get pass the authentication. the warning said  remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.

That too is a very common FAQ; please search before asking, if only to see what a well-formed question with adequate debugging details looks like.

yeah I just fixed it. thanks for the help

Hey i too started using git recently..
I tried this and it was helpful.

I Created a GitHub Repository.
I then cloned the repository.
Then initialized Git in local repositary
Now i was able to Link the Local Repository to GitHub
After this, i added and commited files in repo using git add and git commit commands.
Post then using git Push command, i pushed changes to Git.

Have you tried this? let me know if it worked for you.
